# Using C++11's begin() and end() function to determine array dimension by parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

So I am currently learning C++ (with previous experience in Java and JavaScript) and as far as I am concerned you can't pass an array as argument in C++ like you can in Java. But you can pass a pointer to the first element in the array. So I could iterate through an array like this:

```
bool occurs(int* arrInt, int length, int sought, int& occurrences)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; ++i)
    {
        if (arrInt[i] == sought)
            occurrences++;
    }

    // if occurences > 0 return true, else false
    return occurrences;
}
```

The whole function should basically return a boolean telling me wether the given int (`sought`) was found in the array (`arrInt`) or not. Also I am supplying a little counter via reference (`occurrences`).
But what bugs me is the `length` parameter. C++11 provides those fancy std::begin / cbegin() and std::end / cend() functions to get the first and one past the last element of an array:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4} // arr is basically a pointer to an int, just as the
                      // function parameter of ocurs(int*,int,int,int&)
auto end = std::end(arr); // end points to one past last element
```

But why can't I use my `arrInt` parameter as argument for that function? Then i could get rid of the length parameter:

```
bool occurs(int* arrInt, int sought, int& occurences)
{
    for (auto it = std::begin(arrInt); it != std::end(arrInt); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == sought)
            occurences++;
    }

    // if occurences > 0 return true, else false
    return occurences;
}
```

Am I missing a major concept here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and/or [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)

Comment: @rettichschnidi Thanks for the link but I'm aware of that class, using an vector<int>::iterator would be too easy though, what if a vector was no option for me? :)

Comment: Then a) state this in the question and b) have a look at [std::count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/)

Comment: *"Am I missing a major concept here? "* - Yes. A `std::vector` does this for you. It is the Object Oriented way to use an array. You want an array? Use a vector.

Comment: @Galik I gotta admit I lol'ed at "You want an array? Use a vector." But i'll consider it in the future, thanks.

Comment: @NiklasVest It sounds funny but it is literally true. A `std::vector` according to the standard, manages a *dynamic* array. If you do that in a *procedural* language like `C` you have to remember the pointer and the length. The Object Oriented way to do that is to store the pointer and the length inside an object - an *abstract data type*. It performs everything you would except on the inside. And, because `C++` all access is with *inline* trivial functions that get completely stripped away by the compiler. So its just as *fast* as if you did it all the `C` way.

Comment: @Galik Well you don't really have to "remember" the size since we have (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)) or, when inside a function, incrementing the pointer until encountering a nullptr. But I have to admit a vector is a bit easier to handle! I just thought, maybe I need to use C libraries in the futures, so why not play around a bit. :)

Comment: @NiklasVest "incrementing the pointer until encountering a nullptr" <-- this is wrong for two reasons. First, for C-style strings, you increment until you encounter a null *value*, not a null *pointer*. Secondly, that is only true for C-style *strings*. Your arbitrary int array won't necessarily end in `0`, and could easily have `0` in it as a legit value!

Comment: @Barry At this point i should shut up and let you guys write my code ;) As i said I am still learning C++. Aint there also a null value with pointers to objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your first example:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4} // arr is basically a pointer to an int, just as the
                      // function parameter of ocurs(int*,int,int,int&)
auto end = std::end(arr); // end points to one past last element
```

`arr` is **NOT** "basically a pointer to an int". `arr` is of type `int[4]`. Note that the length is part of the type. As a result, the compiler can easily determine where "one past last element" is. Just add the length.

Where the confusion may come in is that `arr` is *convertible* to (you'll sometimes hear *decays* to) `int*`. But it isn't just a pointer.

---

In your second example:

```
bool occurs(int* arrInt, int sought, int& occurences)
{
    for (auto it = std::begin(arrInt); it != std::end(arrInt); ++it) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`arrInt` **is** just a pointer. As such, how can you know where `end()` is? There's no information here. That's why you need that extra length parameter.

You can instead pass in the full array, but you have to do it by reference (you cannot pass arrays by value, thanks C!). And to do that, you have to make it a function template:

```
template <size_t N>
bool occurs (int (&arrInt)[N], int sought, int& occurrences) {
    ...
}
```

Here, `arrInt` is an array - and its length is encoded in the type (`N`). So you can write `std::end(arrInt)`.

---

`occurs()` is basically rewriting [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), so you could just use that instead:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 8};
int occurrences = std::count(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 3); // yields 2
```

---

Or, even simpler, use `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that *an array is not a pointer*. And so in this example code:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4} // arr is basically a pointer to an int, just as the
                      // function parameter of ocurs(int*,int,int,int&)
```

… the comments are simply wrong.

However, in both C and C++ an array type expression decays to pointer type, with pointer to first item as result, in a context where a pointer is expected. An example that is not such context, is where an array is passed by reference. Another example is when it's used as argument to `sizeof`.

---

With `arrInt` declared as

```
int* arrInt
```

it's just a pointer, with no information about whether it points to a single `int` or to somewhere in an array, and so

```
std::end(arrInt)
```

can't deduce an array size. Normally it deduces that from the array type of the argument. Or from a container's `size` or `end` member (how it's implemented is unspecified, and the same info is available several ways).

---

One possibility is to change your function design, e.g. change it to accept two pointers (or general iterators), like `std::find`.

Another possibility is to use `std::find` in your function.

You can do that because given a start pointer and an array size, you can trivially compute the past-the-end pointer for the array, to use as argument to `std::find`.